# ngTable doesn't come to second last page when last page data is deleted

Tags: angularjs, pagination, ngtable

I am using ngTable with angularJs. I have delete button for every row. When i am deleting data of last page it's not coming to the second last page. It just shows blank page.

**Before -**
on 3rd it has one record like below
[image]

**After -**
after deleting the record on 3rd page. it shows blank table with no pages at the bottom. Ideally it should go the second page.
[image]

How do i refresh the table so that it goes to the second last page after deleting all the records on the last page ??

https://plnkr.co/edit/GeFYGttRJKWO3HCr

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

<title>

AngularJs Table with ng-table module Example

</title>

  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.8.2/angular.js"></script>    
  
  <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.8.2/angular-resource.js"></script>    

<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ng-table@3.0.1/bundles/ng-table.min.css">
<style>.ng-table-sort-header{
    background-color:dimgrey;
    color:#ffffff;
}

.pagination {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin: 20px 0;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.pagination>li {
    display: inline;
}

.pagination>li:first-child>a, .pagination>li:first-child>span {
    margin-left: 0;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
}
.pagination>li>a, .pagination>li>span {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    margin-left: -1px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #337ab7;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.pagination>.active>a{
    z-index: 2;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: default;
    background-color: #337ab7;
    border-color: #337ab7;
}</style>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ng-table@3.0.1/bundles/ng-table.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var app = angular.module("ngtableApp", ["ngTable"]);

app.controller("ngtableCtrl", function ($scope, $filter, NgTableParams) {
$scope.users =[];
$scope.users = [
    { id:1,name: "Madhav Sai", age: 10, location: 'Nagpur' },
    { id:2,name: "Suresh Dasari", age: 30, location: 'Chennai' },
    { id:3,name: "Rohini Alavala", age: 29, location: 'Chennai' },
    { id:4,name: "Praveen Kumar", age: 25, location: 'Bangalore' },
    { id:5,name: "Sateesh Chandra", age: 27, location: 'Vizag' },
    { id:6,name: "Siva Prasad", age: 38, location: 'Nagpur' },
    { id:7,name: "Sudheer Rayana", age: 25, location: 'Kakinada' },
    {id:8, name: "Honey Yemineni", age: 7, location: 'Nagpur' },
    { id:9,name: "Mahendra Dasari", age: 22, location: 'Vijayawada' },
    { id:10,name: "Mahesh Dasari", age: 23, location: 'California' },
    {id:11, name: "Nagaraju Dasari", age: 34, location: 'Atlanta' }
];

$scope.usersTable = new NgTableParams({
    page: 1,
    count: 5,
    
    sorting : {  
        name : 'desc'
    } 
}, 
{
counts:[],
    total: $scope.users.length,
    getData:function (params) {
                console.log('params '+ JSON.stringify(params));
                $scope.data = params.sorting() ? $filter('orderBy')($scope.users, params.orderBy()) : $scope.users;
                $scope.data = params.filter() ? $filter('filter')($scope.data, params.filter()) : $scope.data;
               // $scope.data = $scope.data.slice(0, 20);
                $scope.data = $scope.data.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count());

                return $scope.data;

            }

});

$scope.deleteData = function(obj){
        const indexOfObject = $scope.users.findIndex(object => {
          return object.id === obj.id;
        });
        $scope.users.splice(indexOfObject, 1);
        $scope.usersTable.reload();

}

});

</script>

</head>

<body ng-app="ngtableApp">

<div ng-controller="ngtableCtrl">

<h2>AngularJS ng-table Filtering Example</h2>

<table ng-table ="usersTable" show-filter=true class="table table-bordered table-striped">

<tr ng-repeat="user in data">

<td data-title="'Name'" sortable="'name'" filter="{ 'name': 'text' }">{{user.name}}</td>

<td data-title="'Age'" sortable="'age'" filter="{ 'age': 'text' }">{{user.age}}</td>

<td data-title="'Location'" sortable="'location'" filter="{ 'location': 'text' }">{{user.location}}</td>
<td data-title="'Action'" data-ng-click="deleteData(user)" >delete</td>


</tr>

</table>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```